# In Fallout Shelter, How Fast Does Radiation Heal without RadAway

Tags: fallout-shelter

I had a bit of a water issue, and now my 141 inhabitants all have significant radiation poisoning. Let's say they were at 50% poisoned ... how long would it take to fix? Is there any technique to speed it (e.g. uplevel my RadAway Production Room)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once there is sufficient purified water, radiation poisoning will decrease for dwellers in the vault under normal conditions. 50% radiation poisoning will go away in... about 4 to 6 hours. This cannot be sped up, only supplemented with the use of RadAways.

Comment: This helps, thank you! Quick follow on - does it have to be in the green the whole time you've been away? What if you come back and it's red (but when you shut down, it was green)?

Comment: I don't actually know, since I've not had it in a middle state for a long period of time. My guess is that the poisoning would slowly increase when in the red but not depleted, but that is, again, just a guess.